# What index should I use to convert a numpy array into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a simple numpy array into a pandas dataframe.

`x` is my array, `nam` is the list of the columns names.

```
x = np.array([2,3,1,0])
nam = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
```

I use `pd.DataFrame` to convert `x`

```
y = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=nam)
```

But I have this error message :

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 4), indices imply (4, 4)

I tried to adjust the index parameter but I can't find the solution.

I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
   2      3      1      0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should reshape your input array:

```
In [6]: pd.DataFrame(x.reshape(1,4), columns=nam)
Out[6]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     2     3     1     0
```

or bit more flexible:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(x.reshape(len(x) // len(nam), len(nam)), columns=nam)
Out[11]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     2     3     1     0
```

Answer (score 7):

Another simplier solution with `[]`:

```
x = np.array([2,3,1,0])
nam = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

print (pd.DataFrame([x], columns=nam))
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     2     3     1     0
```